# Stringbuilder Formatting

Tags: c#, string, formatting, padding, stringbuilder

How can i format the StringBuilder for the output below to be aligned in a manner that it's properly padded, Right now it's just a mess!.I am using String Builder to make string in a manner :Stra.append(),Stra.append(" ")

[image: String To Format]

Comment: How would you like to align it differently? It's always going to look somewhat similar to that unless you use a mono-spaced font to display it.

Comment: How and what do you append to the `StringBuilder`? You can format a `double` with specified precision by `toString()` or `string.Format()`

Comment: Maybe AppendLine is what you neeed?

Comment: What is your output destination? Console? A text file? A web page? An excel document?

Comment: @ChrisMantle i would like that the values are equi-distant from each other and from the sides of textbox. Can you guide me to some link for mono-spaced font using string builder?

Comment: @glenatron It's a winform textbox

Comment: @AlvinWong can you give an example?

Comment: So why use a textbox for what appears to be tabular data? Why not chuck it in a tabular structure of some kind?

Comment: @user1514077 StringBuilder has no concept of font. Set your WinForms textbox to use a mono-spaced font like Consolas or Courier New. Then you can use formatting and padding on your numbers to make them fit. As glenatron says though, why not use a data grid, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0,16}", number)`. This will make your number right-aligned with a width of 16.

Comment: @user1514077 I forgot to mention, you can also use something like `{0,16:F5}` as a format string to fix the number of decimal digits that your numbers get.

Comment: Actually i want full resolution so i can't format the numbers, there is also an update to your answer, to properly display it you have to use mono-spaced font as mentioned by Chis, I used your solution with  Arial mono-spaced font, Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use vbtab to insert tabs or vbcrlf to insert a carriage return/line feed ie

```
Stra.append(vbTab)

Stra.append(VbCrLf)
```

Comment: Actually, I checked and it's also available in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx Although C# users would probably uses things like \t and \r\n (or Environment.NewLine)